# wpdb inside foreach loop only returns first result - 2 other similar cases found

Tags: loop, wpdb

@Milo Problem solved, found spaces in the array $arrname.

I was trying to get post id using post_name. First of all I stored all post_name in an array an then loop through the array to use the key variable in a wpdb query to get post id, really strange though, it only returns the first post id.

As you can see I tried to output the array and it works fine, outputs every key value in that array,but the wpdb query only return the first result(tried switch the order of the key values in the array, confirmed that it only output the first result.).

Any ideas?

```
global $wpdb;
$rawname=$_POST['image_post_name'];
$arrname=explode(",", $rawname);
foreach ($arrname as &$value) {
$mypostid = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name='$value'"));
echo $mypostid;
echo $value;}
```

Tried to add exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );, found out only the first query got executed.

string(49) "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='unamed3'" last query, "String(49)"?

Comment: Found this post, similar problem.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/wpdb-get-results-returns-good-result-only-in-first-foreach-iteration

Comment: Tried to add exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );, found out only the first query got executed.

Comment: string(49) "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='unamed3'" last query, "String(49)"?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27526/wpdb-insert-inserting-multiple-rows another similar case.

Comment: does the string of values have spaces after the commas? there's nothing wrong with that code as long as your post name values are correct.

Comment: Add debug data to the question. Do not hide that in comments.

Comment: @Milo Thanks,man! That's where I found the problem, it's working now.

Comment: @lancerq - this is why I suggested sanitation ..

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer, and then accept it? Thanks

Comment: If you have found the solution, post it as an answer, do not edit your question

Comment: Also, there is no need for a `wpdb` query, a WP_Query call or a `get_post` call will do this without the raw SQL

Answer (score 1):

OP found the solution:

> Problem solved, found spaces in the array $arrname.

I'm posting as a brief answer to tidy up our site.  If anyone would like to up vote it to get the question closed then that would be great :-)

Alternatively, express your view on the quality of question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is data validation -
You should always use [sanitation functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) when dealing with Database.
Try to see if it helps..